# How to make Array.toString() in IE9 compatible with modern browsers

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, dom, tostring

I want to assign an array value to an attribute in DOM:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
elem.setAttribute('value', myArray)
```

in modern browsers you have the result:

```
<input value="1,2,3">
```

but in older ones (up to IE9):

```
<input value="[object]">
```

`JSON.stringify` is not a solution because this will generate:

```
<input value="[1,2,3]">
```

The problem is that `myArray.toString()` in modern browsers outputs:

```
1,2,3
```

while in older ones:

```
[object]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `elem.setAttribute('value', myArray.join(','));` should work in any browser.

Comment: the code is deep in the stack where values come automatically and I cannot change that piece of code. (possible values are numbers strings, and apparently arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're intent on having the `toString` method, you could overwrite it like this:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];

Array.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.join(', ');
}

console.log(myArray.toString()); //1, 2, 3
```

This should work in most older browsers.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/KUzZL/

Comment: @John you removed the "Hope this helps"... why?

Comment: That's not relevant.. It's like "Hi", "Thanks" and so on.

Comment: @KyleMuir It's noise and not relevant to the Answer. I'm sure there is a better meta post regarding removing noise from posts, but the best i could find right now is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify(array)` instead of `.toString()`. Also, you can write a function like this that will convert your array to string.

```
function arrayToString(array) {
   var arrayStr = JSON.stringify([1, 2, 3]);
   arrayStr = arrayStr.substring(1);
   arrayStr = arrayStr.substring(0, arrayStr.length -1);
   return arrayStr;
}
```

or even shortener:

```
var str = array.join(",");
```

Example:

```
arrayToString([1, 2, 3, 4]); // returns "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

Also, you can extend the prototype of `Array` overwriting the `toString()` function:

```
Array.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.join(",");
}
```